# Ruby on Rails, taking information from multiple tables to display in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table, view, erb

So `tasking.point_of_contact` is an integer value that is the same number as the `user.id` whose `name` (name is defined as `:firstname` + `:lastname`) I want to display.

How can I take the value in `tasking.point_of_contact` and use it to call the `name` of the corresponding `user.id`?

Right now I have:

```
<td><%= tasking.point_of_contact %></td>
```

I want that to display the `name` of the `user` whose `user.id` equals `tasking.point_of_contact`.

The relationship between user and taskings is a many-to-many.

I hope I've give you enough information. I may have been redundant, but I just want to be clear.

Comment: Please post the source of tasking and point_of_contact (user) active_record models

Comment: When formatting code, please use backticks (`) and not bold (**). See the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more details.

Comment: Cool, I'll format it with backticks next times, I'm still new to this! Thank you!

Comment: Here is my **Tasking** model:

`
class Tasking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "point_of_contact"
  has_many :userhastasks, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :description, :detail_date, :location, :point_of_contact, :task_name, :completed
end
`

Comment: Here is my **User** model:
`
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :userhastasks, :dependent => :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :firstname, :lastname, :company, :classyear, :role
def name
 lastname + ", " + firstname + " " + company
end

end
`

Comment: Still messed up the backticks somehow....

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't set up your relationship in your tasking model yet, you want to do that.

```
belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "point_of_contact"
```

Then, where ever you're doing the initial query

```
@tasking = Tasking.where(whatever)
```

You'll want to eager load the users so you don't get a N+1 issue (you can google this, just an efficiency thing).

```
@tasking = Tasking.includes(:user).where(whatever you want to find)
```

Then in your view you'll do

```
tasking.user.name
```

Comment: Specifying the class `User` for a relationship already called `user` should be redundant.

Comment: true, didn't really think about that

Comment: Hey so i'm confused where 
`@tasking = Tasking.includes(:user).where(whatever you want to find)`
is supposed to go. In my controller, model, or view? I've updated the tasking model as you've suggested. And I'm unclear as to what goes in `(whatever you want to find)`? Do you mean something like `.where( user.id = tasking.point_of_contact )`?

Appreciate the help, still very new at RoR!

Comment: @dylan Where are you getting the tasking variable from now? That has to come from somewhere, right? The `@tasking = Tasking.includes(:user).where(arbitrary)` goes in the controller, in the action for whatever view you want. Then in that view, you can use the @tasking variable. If you want all tasks, you can do `@tasking = Tasking.includes(:user).all`. The `.where` is just a way for you to filter which Tasking items you want. You could say `.where(:active => true)`, if you had an active column that was boolean. That kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are some helper methods generated automatically when you have a [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) relationship. Specifically, the others [generated method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) should be helpful. In your case, it would be `tasking.users`. However, I'm not sure your design is correct...

Comment: Please don't use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. It's a relic from Rails 1 that is a lot more difficult to use than `has_many x, :through y` type relationships.

Comment: I will note that in **no** place in the source is `has_and_belongs_to_many` marked as deprecated.

Comment: I didn't say deprecated, it's still fully supported, but that doesn't mean it's better. It's absolutely not. Any metadata stored in that relationship is very difficult to edit, and will be joined in to the model it's associated with. The `:through` mechanism is much more robust, giving you a first-class model you can use to edit any metadata, and in many cases you'll find you'll be working with those join records directly, as when presenting a list of check-boxes on a form where relationships can be added or removed as required.